# How should I document singletons?

Tags: jsdoc

I'm not sure which tag I should use to document singletons like the following:

```
var singleton = {
  c: 1,
  f: function(){
    return this.c;
  }
}
```

When I use `@namespace` the member function `f` will be declared as `<static>`, and I'ts not a namespace anyway. But it's obviously neither a `@class`.  Is there a separate tag or trick you use for singletons?